# How to select values from 1 column, where certain columns in different tables = different values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is kind of tricky. I need to pull out values in land_info from land .. However I need several WHEREs: partner.type = 'Studie', land.land = 'USA', sprog.sprog = 'Engelsk' and lastly udd.udd = 'Bygning'... the partner and sprog tables are many to many relations.. and therefore have a table inbetween called partner_has_sprog .. the same with partner and udd = partner_has_udd...

I've made this sql fiddle with the tables.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdd7a4 ... and basicly.. What I need to select, is the land.land_info from the 2nd partner (the one in USA) .. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just call partner from sprog with the necessary land of tricky. And the same with... oh, I can't keep this up. However, I doubt that Germany, America, or Britain are going to change their country codes anytime soon, so that might be a normalization step too far!

Comment: USE OR statement for multiple conditions @Strawberry hahah

Comment: by the way, land is varchar(100) in partner table and varchar(40) in land table. You ill got a lot of trouble to join lands with more than 40 characters

Comment: Don't store the `land` text in multiple tables (`partner` and `land`). You have the land id in the `partner` table and that should be enough.

Comment: The fiddle is a bit messy :P .. my real db is a little more neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your just trying to link all the tables together it isn't too difficult, you just need to use an `INNER JOIN` for each:

```
SELECT
   P.partid
  ,P.type
  ,L.land_info
  ,L.land
  ,UDD.udd
  ,SPROG.sprog
FROM partner AS P
  INNER JOIN land AS L
    ON P.landid = L.landid

  INNER JOIN partner_has_udd AS PUDD
    ON P.partid = PUDD.partner_partid

    INNER JOIN udd AS UDD
      ON PUDD.udd_uddid = UDD.uddid

  INNER JOIN partner_has_sprog AS PSPR
    ON P.partid = PSPR.partner_partid

    INNER JOIN sprog AS SPROG
      ON PSPR.sprog_sprogid = SPROG.sprogid
;
```

And here's the updated SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29990f/2/0

You had a typo in the Scheme section of your SQL Fiddle and were inserting the `partner_has_sprog` values into the `sprog` table.

Comment: This did the trick with some small additions. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just it?

```
select l.land_info
from land l
join partner p on p.land = l.land
where p.landid = 2;
```